# Visual Basic GetAddress (Hyperlink) from Excel String

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VB in my excel that extracts the hyperlink from a pasted cell:

```
Function GetAddress(HyperlinkCell As Range) As String
If HyperlinkCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
GetAddress = Replace(HyperlinkCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address, "mailto:", "NOTHING HERE")
Else
GetAddress = ""
End If
End Function
```

The problem is it strips anything in the hyperlink after # e.g.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_support#Tier.2FLevel_1_.28T1.2FL1.29

becomes

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_support

Any suggestions on how to request the whole string?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Function GetAddress(HyperlinkCell As Range) As String
    If HyperlinkCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        GetAddress = Replace(HyperlinkCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address, "mailto:", "NOTHING HERE")
        GetAddress = GetAddress & "#" & HyperlinkCell.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress
    Else
        GetAddress = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up finding a URL VB that seemed to work too: I'm not sure how to paste inside the code box like you did so posting here: Function GetURL(cell As Range, _
Optional default_value As Variant)
'Lists the Hyperlink Address for a Given Cell
'If cell does not contain a hyperlink, return default_value
If (cell.Range("A1").Hyperlinks.Count <> 1) Then
GetURL = default_value
Else
GetURL = cell.Range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).Address & "#" & cell.Range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress
End If
End Function